# Javascript: "Error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null"

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this error:

```
resultsWrapper.appendChild(option);
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

I read a few solutions here before uploading this. The script tag is at the bottom of my HTML file and when I checked using Chrome console, the element is getting created and defined. But when it gets to the `appendChild()` line it is set to `null`. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Below is the code:

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
const resultsWrapper = document.querySelector('.results');

const onInput = async event => {
   const movies = await fetchData(event.target.value);

   dropdown.classList.add('is-active');
   for (let movie of movies) {
       const option = document.createElement('a');

       option.classList.add('dropdown-item'); 
       option.innerHTML = `
            <img src="${movie.Poster}"/>
            ${movie.Title}      
       `;

       resultsWrapper.appendChild(option);
   }
};
```

Comment: `console.log` it *inside the function*. I strongly suspect the element is not there when you first try to find it.

Comment: I call it inside the function, right before the appendChild line. Look how weird: https://ibb.co/cgcSsFN